# Улучшает производительность в php7.4 типизация или это сделано для удобства в отладке?

Tags: php, ооп, php7.4

Улучшает производительность в php7.4 типизация или это сделано для удобства в отладке? А также играет ли роль на производительность, если базовые классы сделать абстрактными. Спасибо

Comment: а почему отладки? это просто убирает часть работы по проверке валидности передаваемых параметров. на производительность вроде не влияет, по крайней мере не должно быть заметно. Абстрактность базовых классов только раздует таблицу виртуальных методов (или ее аналог), в общем увеличение цепочки наследования плюсов к производительности не добавит.

Comment: @teran, главное, чтобы производительность не упала от типизации. У меня закралась мысль в голове, что возможно интерпретатор выполняет дополнительные поверки. Насчет абстрактного класса, вопрос был в том, что я хочу создать базовый класс и наследовать его в других классах. Но использовать для этой задачи обычный класс или абстрактный?

Comment: само по себе проверяться не будет, естественно где то проверки эти появились. сможете ли вы заметить разницу в производительности? маловероятно, как мне кажется. По абстрактности, думаю, не будет разницы от абстрактного будете наследовать или от обычного.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то разработчика говорили о падении производительности при добавлении типизации. Как раз из-за дополнительных проверок. Но если для вас 0.1 - 1 % потери крайне беспокоит, то вы выбрали не тот язык программирования. Этот как известный холивар про одинарные и двойные кавычки.

Comment: @ArchDemon там скорее 0.001-0.01 будет.